# install bitbake ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center

I have not seen any bitbake package exist in ubuntu software center or sudo apt-get install bitbake also not working.

Can someone help me to install bitbake on ubuntu14.04?

Thanks

Comment: The newest version I can find is for 12.04, so either ask the developer to update it or install 12.04... https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bitbake

Comment: @Alvar: Is there any way to install for ubuntu14.04?